# There is no 'Rigidbody' attached to the "Player" game object, but a script is trying to access it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello ijust started messing around with unity and this is is one of my first error messages i got. And i can't seem to understand it.

Here is the full message

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'Rigidbody' attached to the "Player" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
>   You probably need to add a Rigidbody to the game object "Player". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
>   UnityEngine.Rigidbody.get_velocity () <0x602a2350 + 0x0006a> in :0
>   Player.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:25)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxIkc.jpg

And here is my player script in c#

```
[SerializeField]
private Rigidbody playerBody;
private Vector3 inputVector;
private bool jump;


// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    playerBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    float speed = 10f;

    inputVector = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, playerBody.velocity.y, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed);
    transform.LookAt(transform.position + new Vector3(inputVector.x, 0, inputVector.z));
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        jump = true;
    }
}


private void FixedUpdate()
{
    playerBody.velocity = inputVector;
    if (jump)
    {
        playerBody.AddForce(Vector3.up * 20f, ForceMode.Impulse);
        jump = false;
    }

}
```

Note:

I didn't have this problem yesterday, i closed unity and today when i opend it i had this issue.
Not sure if it has anything to do with it... seems weird.

Comment: You need to have the Rigidbody component attached to the gameoject before you can access it via script.

Comment: But it is, no `? How can i check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the screenshot you posted, there is no Rigidbody component. 
Click on the button Add Component and select Rigidbody there.